# Performance Monitor Processor Time counter blank data

Tags: performance-monitoring, perfmon, database-performance

I setup a simple data collector with Performance Monitor to collect Processor time(CPU Usage in %) and SQL Statistics: Batch Requests/sec @ 15 second intervals to see if i can get some baselines and report back to our vendor.

I started the counter on July 6th at 2:30PM; It recorded the values fine up to July 7th 12:15AM, then the  Processor time counter stopped recording at that time, but the Batch requests/sec are still getting counted. It recorded a total of 2332 rows without any blanks, then after than the Processor time counter stopped recording. ( There's a small gap between 12:15 and 12:18AM on the 7th for 7 rows for the Batch requests counter, but it continues afterwards down to over 10k rows).
Its setup to write to a csv.

I recreated this perfmon counter more than once; Previously i had other multiple other counters in the data collector(Disk IO, Network IO, avl memory...), and the same issue occurred ( Either the CPU Time would stop recording after a certain time or the Batch requests; All other counters didn't seem to get affected).
I have a separate data collector that only has the Processor Time counter for our multiple application servers, those seem to run fine without any missing values.

Has anyone seen similar issues with performance counters that just stop recording for a specific counter? Should i try increasing the interval to 1minute instead of 15 seconds?

Comment: UPDATE: The 2 new data collectors that ran overnight both stopped recording just after 12AM...In the first data collector for the SQL CPU Usage and Batch requests, the CPU counter stopped at 12:19. The App server CPU Usage stopped recording all CPU counter for each server after 12:22AM....We're also looking into possible network intermittent issues occuring overnight...